# Remove first line from bigfile using bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a text file and want to remove the first line (header), to read the file without header into a pipeline. This seems like a trivial question that has been answered many times, but due to the size of the files I'm facing, the solutions i found so far were not working. For my test runs i used `echo "$(tail -n +2 "$FILE_NAME")" > "$FILE_NAME"`, but running this with my a bigger file results in the following error: `bash: xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744071562067968 bytes (1679360 bytes allocated)` Is there any method that edits the file in place? Loading them into the memory wont work, some of my files are up to 400 Gb in size. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am not surpirsed. You pass the output of `tail` as an argument of `echo`. The maximum argument length is by far exceeded here. You actually don't need the `echo`, you could just do `$ tail -n +2 file > file.new`. Remark, you will have to duplicate the file, you cannot pipe into the same file so this `$ tail -n +2 file > file` will not work!

Comment: It's generally better to design your on-disk format to not need this kind of operation, at least if you'd be doing it frequently. If you're building a queue, for example, one way to make both push and pop efficient is to split content into two files, one forward and one reverse, so you can efficiently shorten the reversed one to remove things off the top, or lengthen the forward one to add things at the bottom; then all you need to do is arrange to move content between them when necessary.

Comment: Using a ring buffer and just moving the pointers into it is even easier, if you're guaranteed not to need more than a constant amount of storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code like this:

```
awk 'NR!=1 {print}' input_file >output file
```

This will send to output file all but first line. You can use this construction to do your operations:

```
awk 'NR!=1 {print}' input_file|operation1|operation2...
```

Changing your command on this way can do the work:

```
tail -n +2 "$FILE_NAME" > "${FILE_NAME}.new"
```

This will need double diskspace

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to address the "edit the file in place" portion of the question, although it appears that was not really what you were looking for.  You will find many solutions describing features that claim to do in-place editing, but usually those solutions don't actually edit the file at all.  Instead, they write to a temporary file and then overwrite the original with the temporary file.  (eg, `sed --in-place` is a common solution which writes to a temporary file).  Editing the file in place is something that you almost never actually want to do, since mutating a file is dangerous.  Truly, if you believe you want to edit a file in place, give it serious thought and assume that you are wrong.  However, if for some reason you really do need to do it, it's probably safest to just do it:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
int is_regular(int, const char *);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        const char *rpath = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin";
        const char *wpath = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdout";
        FILE *fr = argc > 1 ? xfopen(rpath, "r") : stdin;
        FILE *fw = argc > 1 ? xfopen(wpath, "r+") : stdout;
        char buf[BUFSIZ];
        int c;
        size_t rc;
        off_t length = 0;

        /* Discard the first line */
        while( (c = getc(fr)) != EOF && c != '\n' ) {
                ;
        }
        if( c != EOF) while( (rc = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZ, fr)) > 0) {
                size_t wc;
                wc = fwrite(buf, 1, rc, fw);
                length += wc;
                if( wc!= rc) {
                        break;
                }
        }
        if( fclose(fr) ) {
                err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", rpath);
        }
        if( is_regular(fileno(fw), wpath) && ftruncate(fileno(fw), length)) {
                err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", wpath);
        }
        if( fclose(fw)) {
                err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", wpath);
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
        FILE *fp = fopen(path, mode);
        if( fp == NULL ) {
                perror(path);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return fp;
}

int
is_regular(int fd, const char *name)
{
        struct stat s;
        if( fstat(fd, &s) == -1 ) {
                perror(name);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return !!(s.st_mode & S_IFREG);
}
```

By being explicit, it's pretty clear that you can easily lose data in the file.  But if you want to avoid reading the entire file into memory, or avoid having two copies on some backing media at the same time, there's no way to avoid doing that and any solution which obscures that risk is fooling you.  So making it explicit and knowing where the dangers lie is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Tail is reasonably efficient for this operation.

The issue is with you wanting to overwrite the original file.

Using bash `"$()"` to defer the creation of the output file means bash has to hold the content in memory, hence the error message. For large files you would be better off writing the output to a temporary file, then use `mv` to move that over the original.

When sed is used in overwrite mode it does exactly this (for anything over a few lines).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 1d "$FILE_NAME"
```

It runs `sed` with the verysimple script `1d` which picks the first line (the `1` selector) and deletes it (the `d` command). Thanks to the in-place option `-i` your file will be overwritten without using an intermediate file.

Even though you do not bother with an intermediate file, `sed` uses his own intermediate file internally. Your disk usage will suffer up to twice the file size during this operation.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `-i` (in-place) option with `sed` to write the change back to the input file instead of printing the result to stdout:

```
sed -i '1d' FILE
```